# How to set max value for LinearProgress in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `LinearProgress` from material ui in my page and my max value for `LinearProgress` are not `100` all the time, sometimes it can be 10, 20, 5 .. . I tried doing

```
   <LinearProgress
            variant="determinate"
            value={section.Remaining_Qty}
            maxValue={50} // added             
    />
```

but it doesn't work. Are there any other ways to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use formula to get dynamic value with `maxValue={100}` and dynamic `maxValue` that you have it `(10,20,5...)`

**Final code**

```
let dynamicMaxValue = 5;

<LinearProgress
  variant="determinate"
  value={(section.Remaining_Qty * 100)/dynamicMaxValue}
  maxValue={100}
/>
```

`dynamicMaxValue = 5` and `section.Remaining_Qty = 2` value will `be = 40%`

Remember `section.Remaining_Qty <= dynamicMaxValue`

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I am sure it will work, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula in the value prop:

```
Math.round((100 / maxValue) * currentValue)
```